# precision in variables extracted from array using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am loading an array using `numpy.genfromtxt`. I extract a variable from the array and save it into another .txt file, however the output will have many trailing digits.
Here is an example of my script:

```
import numpy as np
import csv

data_points = np.genfromtxt('input_arrray.txt', dtype = None)
# dtype = None since the array contains numbers and strings      

csvfile = "/home/User/Desktop/output_array.txt"
with open(csvfile, "w") as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output, delimiter='\t')
    for row in range(len(data_points)):
        parameter = data_points[row][5]
        writer.writerow([parameter])
```

Let's say the value in the `input_array` was `0.33625` in the `output_array.txt` it will be `0.33624999999999999`'

To fix this problem I am using:

```
writer.writerow(['%1.5f' % parameter])
```

However, I am not satisfied by the results. My original array is made of 1900 rows and 38 columns. I want to extract 10 columns out of the 38. But when I use the `'%2.5f% parameter` my data is not aligned.

Is there another way to fix this problem?

Comment: If you parse the file yourself, you should be able to avoid this problem e.g. a = '1.225'; float(a) == 1.225. Maybe you want to know how to configure numpy.genfromtxt to not have the rounding error?

Comment: since I haven't heard from you, did the answer below work fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force to keep the original data as string:

```
data_points = np.gengromtxt('input_array.txt', dtype=str)
```

and then write using `np.savetxt` with ``` fmt='%s`` to avoid the conversion ```string -> float` that is causing the round error:

```
np.savetxt('output.txt', data_points, fmt='%s')
```